# Get Enter key event in windows phone 8.1 and do something

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

> SOLVED, So i was not subscribing to the event, dumb mistake :/  adding
>   KeyDown="NumKeyDown" solves the problem.
>
> ```
>  <TextBox x:Name="searchBox" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"  KeyDown="NumKeyDown"/>
> ```

---

Apparently i want to do  something using the data i am getting in textbox which is in hub section. I dont want to have a button explicitly for that rather i want to get into a function that is called when enter key is pressed from my windows phone 8.1, i.e. on enter key pressed event. i am using this function but can't seem to help.. this function is placed in mainpage.cs and hubsection and textbox are in mainpage.xaml

```
 private async void NumKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            var message_dialog = new MessageDialog("Dial *100# directly from keypad for warid balance inquiry. Thank you!");
            // Show the message dialog
            await message_dialog.ShowAsync();

        }


      }
```

Comment: show how you subscribe the event

Comment: I solved it after your hint of subscribing the event (I was not subscribing the event), Thanks ^^